# TCP Congestion algorithm - Tcp Westwood or Tcp westwood plus?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

I have executed this "**ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/ipv4/**" in my linux 2.16.36 . There i can see a list of algorithms.tcp_westwood is listed in that list . is that tcp_westwood or tcp_westwood+ ?

Comment: The backticks around `uname -r` are being interpreted as markdown formatting.  You might want to use the alternate shell syntax of `$(uname -r)` instead to make your question clearer, as in `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125105730/http://c3lab.poliba.it/index.php?title=Westwood:Linux) suggests that westwood now refers to westwood+.